# Another matlab figure question

Tags: matlab

I want to graph \$h[n] = \frac{1}{n+1} \ n\in [0,29] \$

I tried the next code, but won't compile:

```
n=linspace(0,29,30);               
h =1/(1+n);                                   
figure                                                  
stem (n,h);
```

Comment: This is off topic for EE. Maybe someone can direct you to a more appropriate stack with subject matter experts on mathlab.

Comment: This would be on-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Matlab is not a compiled language, it's interpreted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a dot in front of the divide symbol (this means array divide as opposed to matrix divide):

```
n=linspace(0,29,30);
h =1./(1+n);
figure
stem (n,h);
```

Resulting Graph:

[image: Matlab Example]

To find out more, type `help .` - you will get something like this (this is only part of the result, as it's rather long...):

```
>> help .
  Operators and special characters.

  Arithmetic operators.
    plus       - Plus                               +    
    uplus      - Unary plus                         +    
    minus      - Minus                              -    
    uminus     - Unary minus                        -    
    mtimes     - Matrix multiply                    *    
    times      - Array multiply                    .*    
    mpower     - Matrix power                       ^    
    power      - Array power                       .^    
    mldivide   - Backslash or left matrix divide    \    
    mrdivide   - Slash or right matrix divide       /    
    ldivide    - Left array divide                 .\    
    rdivide    - Right array divide                ./
```

Comment: I would like to add that `n=0:30;` is cleaner and easier. In practice, this error is solved by adding dots util it works. Eventually, you will know the cases in which it is needed.

Comment: @Serge - agreed, a simple integer array might be better. Matlab gives you plenty of hints on the errors too.